# Error with FirebaseArduino library. nodeMCU-ESP8266, Arduino, Firebase

Tags: firebase, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

my code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>

#define WIFI_SSID "NAME"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "PSW"
#define FIREBASE_HOST "example-53ffa-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "example"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Inicializamos el serial a 9600 baudios
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

  Serial.println("Conectando");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) //Realizando conexion
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("Conexion Exitosa");

  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH); // Conectamos con la base de datos

  Firebase.setInt("Entero", 25);
  if (Firebase.success()) {
    Serial.println("Ok");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Conexion fallida");
  }

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

and this is my error:

```
In file included from D:\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/Firebase.h:29,
                 from D:\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/FirebaseArduino.h:22,
                 from D:\Arduino\esp8266_firebase\esp8266_firebase.ino:2: D:\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/FirebaseError.h:7:1: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'enum'
    7 | enum FIREBASE_ERROR_CODES {
      | ^~~~
exit status 1
Error compilando para la tarjeta NodeMCU 0.9 (ESP-12 Module).
```

I've looked for problems in Firebase.h and FirebaseArduino.h and i haven't see any problem.
You can find the library here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino

**Please help me! thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

Finally i could solve the problem.

nodeMCu-ESP8266, FirebaseArduino library and ArduinoJson library didn’t work with new versions.

I can run the program with ArduinoJson v.5.13.5, esp8266 v.2.4.1